# How does Wild Shape interact with the Animal Soul feat and the Animal Growth spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, druid, wild-shape

The druid in my group took the Animal Soul feat. This brought up using Wild Shape with the *animal growth* spell.

I don't think they work together, by the rules as intended - but if they do work together, how would that work? Both Wild Shape and *animal growth* affect Strength, Constitution, and natural armor.

My reasons for thinking they are not intended to work together is by how they changed the wording.  The 1st printing stated that *animal growth* would work, but that line was later removed.

In what is, as far as I know, the most current version of the spell, it states
"ignore harmful magic that cannot affect your wild side". Because of that, I am assuming the sole intent of the feat is to protect you from harmful spells.

Comment: You may want to clarify why you think they are conflicting, or might not work together. (I say this as it has been flagged as unclear)

Comment: You are making reference to various printings. It may be prudent to write into this the relevant quotes from those features that you believe are in conflict with each other.

Answer (score 2):

## A Wild Shaped Druid is not a valid target for Animal Growth Spell, even with this feat

The [Animal Growth](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animal-growth/) spell description specify that the target must be an animal (Gargantuan or smaller). Therefore only creatures with the [animal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/) type are valid targets, which is not the case of most of standards races available to the players (most of them are [humanoid](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Humanoid) type).

The Wild Shape feature of the druid states:

> This ability functions like the *beast shape I* spell, except as noted
>   here.

The *except as noted here* part changes some duration, action cost or other details, but doesn't change anything about what I will now detail.

[Beast Shape I](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape) is a spell of the Trasmutation school and Polymorph subschool. It is stated in the [Polymorph](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) rules that :

> While these spells **make you appear to be the creature**, granting you a
>   +10 bonus on Disguise skill checks, they do not grant you all of the
>   abilities and powers of the creature.

(Emphasis mine)

Therefore as it isn't explicitly mentioned anywhere in the Beast Shape spell description or druid Wild Shape feature, the Wild Shape doesn't alter the druid creature type, it only makes him *appear* like an animal.

The feat [Animal Soul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/animal-soul/) states:

> You can choose not to allow spells and effects to effect you if they would not be capable of affecting both your original creature type and the animal creature type.

This feat only allows to not be affected by some spells if they cannot affect both creature and animal types, which can be a useful defensive feature, but as for the Beast Shape and Wild Shape descriptions, it never intends to *give* the animal type. Hence having or not having this feat doesn't change anything to the situation.

Unless the druid in your group already is an animal (what I doubt), he doesn't qualify as a valid target for the [Animal Growth](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animal-growth/) spell, even while using Wild Shape.

Now even if this combination doesn't work, I'll answer your concern about multiple bonuses for AC and ability scores as this situation can happen in other circumstances.

An important rule to know about bonuses is:

> Most bonuses have a type, and as a general rule, bonuses of the same type are not cumulative (do not “stack”)—only the greater bonus granted applies.

Very few bonuses types do stack with themselves (dodge bonuses for example), and if you have a doubt, you can check it on this [page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary/), on the bonus table. If it is not explicitly stated that a bonus stacks with itself, as for the dodge bonus, it doesn't. Untyped bonuses however, do stack with themselves.

Therefore if this combination of Wild Shape (based on the Beast Shape spell) and Animal Growth would have worked, as both Animal Growth and Beast Shape give size bonuses to ability scores and Natural Armor bonus to AC, they would not stack and the druid would benefit only of the higher bonus for each concerned ability score and for the AC.

Comment: On the subject of stacking, it's worth mentioning both spells (Animal Growth and Beast Shape) are Size and Natural Armor bonuses (although Animal Growth is phrased weirdly, it still applies)

Answer (score 1):

### [Animal Soul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/animal-soul/) is a protective effect

The [Animal Soul](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/animal-soul/) feat doesn't grant you the *animal* type. It simply requires for the effect to affect *creatures* in general (ie: *Charm Monster*) for you to be affected. So you are immune to *Charm Person*, *Daze*, *Hold Person*, etc. Unless you decide to allow it to affect you.

You are no longer a valid *humanoid* for spells, because your soul is half-humanoid and half-animal now. But your creature type remains *humanoid* for other rules purposes.